# How to create the code using signalR in asp.net core and angular and how to run the code in chat application

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to create the chat application for this I have to connect the signalR with angular for making connections I know angular but I don't know the dot net core .

I have created the new project asp dot net core in VS code and also created the new angular application in VS code

My requirement is how to write the code and run the code to create the chat application using angular and dot net code with signalR

can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the link below. The detailed code for both the client(**Angular**) and server(**Asp net Core**) is there.

[SignalR Chat App](https://medium.com/linkit-intecs/how-to-create-a-chat-app-with-asp-net-core-3-1-signalr-and-angular-10-a7fde1e70933)

Don't forget to upvote and mark this answer as correct if it helps